# How to add a delay to Rails controller for testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I'm testing the front end of a web application and want to test how some of the transitions appear with various delays in between AJAX requests.  Is there any way I can add a `sleep(1500)` to my controller to delay the response?

Comment: Just add the sleep(1000) call to your controller action.

Comment: The default unit for sleep in RoR is _seconds_!!  Added sleep 1.5 to the controller and life is good.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Controller like so:

```
def catalog
  #Makes the request pause 1.5 seconds
  sleep 1.5

  ...
end
```

Even better: only add the sleep for the dev environment.

Answer (score 19):

Elaborating on accepted answer. If you have some base controller like the default `ApplicationController` which is extended by any other controller you may define the following filter:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # adds 1s delay only if in development env
  before_action if: "Rails.env.development?" do
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

Where:
**1** is number of seconds to wait before returning any response, see [sleep](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep) docs

This filter will be triggered **only if** your application is in **development** environment and it will add desired delay **to every request** processed by your application.